# C++ passing by reference in constructor

Tags: c++, oop

So I am making a program in C++ and my main method has to construct an object that takes as a parameter a vector.

This is my code:

```
int main() {
  vector<Seller> *staff = new vector<Seller>;

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    staff->push_back(Seller(i));
  }

  BookStore store(*staff);

  deque<Book> books;
  books = store.getBooks();
}
```

So, these are some pretty simple Object-Oriented concepts I think.

My goals are:

First, initializing an empty vector of sellers. A Seller is an object that has a constructor:

```
Seller(int i);
```

And represents, of course, a seller.

Then, I want to fill in the vector with actual Sellers. These are constructed in the for loop.

Then, I want to create a Store, which takes as an argument the sellers that work there.

Finally, I create a new deque called books, and I assign to it the value of books in the Store class. The initialisation of the Books deque is done in the constructor of the Store:

```
Store::Store(vector<Seller> &sellers) {
  this->sellers = sellers;
  this->books = deque<Book> (100, "Harry Potter");
}
```

So this is the code and I am wondering if I am making a mistake in the passing arguments to new constructors part.

I am a bit confused when passing by reference so I am asking for a bit on help on that part. I have two main questions:

1) Are there any errors there, considering how I want to run my program? Consider also that in the rest of the main method (not included here) I constantly change the value of the books deque.
2) Is there any way to replace an element in a deque without having to erase and insert?

Is there a built-in function replace? If not, is the below code going to work if I just want to replace a value in the deque?

For example, if the deque is like that:

```
3 4 5 2
```

And it (an iterator) has value 2.

Then I want the deque to become:

```
3 4 6 2
```

When doing:

```
books.erase(it);
books.insert(it, 6);
```

Thanks for any tips or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here a short analysis.

Firstly, the unique real error I found: `staff` is defined as a pointer and is given a value with `new` but is never released. You should anyway avoid using raw pointers, so either create the object on the stack:

```
vector<Seller> staff{};
```

or use a smart pointer

```
auto staff = make_unique<vector<Seller>>{};
```

(you will then have to learn something about the ownership semantics, so as you still are a beginner I'd recommend the first solution).

Then, notice how the line

`this->sellers = sellers;`

in `Store::Store` will make **a copy** of the `sellers` vector, which probably is not what you meant. If you wanted your store to reference the variable created on `main()`, you should redefine your `Store` as

```
class Store {
   // ...
   vector<Seller>& sellers;
   //...
};
```

and the constructor as

```
Store::Store(vector<Seller> &sellers) :
   sellers{sellers}  // reference member variables must be given a value before the body of the constructor begins
{
  books = deque<Book> (100, "Harry Potter");
}
```

For the same reason, your line

```
books = store.getBooks();
```

will make a copy of the `deque` (but maybe in this case it was intended).

Finally, C++ offers many container manipulating functions under the `<algorithms>` library. Take a look at [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). But if you already have an iterator to the element you want to replace, you do not need such algorithms, just write:

```
*it = 6;
```